# Cannot install Keentools Facebuilder for Blender on Macbook

Tags: add-on

I am new to Blender and I have installed Blender v2.82a on my 
MacBook Air running Catalina 10.15.4
I have downloaded "keentools_2.0.2_facebuilder_for_blender.zip".
When I navigate to it through preferences and add on, I cannot highlight it to install.[image]

Comment: You are not supposed to install from the unzipped folder. Have you tried to install from the ".zip" file ? Second from the bottom on your picture ?

Comment: Yes, I thought that the zip file is what we needed. If I try to click on it, nothing happens. Can I install it manually like placing it into a specific folder? If so, where do I find this folder on my Mac? Thank you for responding. :-)

Comment: Still can’t install it 